# Display product without categories in virtuemart backend

Tags: product, backend, virtuemart, administration

I use Virtuemart 2.6.12. I need to display only products without categories in the Administration>>Products, but I can't find any solution for this.

Can anybody help me, how to filter products as above?

Comment: What do you mean under "to filter"? Do you need to hide categories or filter products in some way?